# Resolving a GitHub Issue from a Project Card via the RESTful SDK

Tags: github, github-api, octokit-js

I'm using octokit (https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v18#projects-list-cards) to interact with my Project and Issues in my repo. I have the project_cards in a list, but I'd like to make some changes to the labels on the issue when I move from column to column.

As near as I can tell (https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/projects#list-project-cards), the only way to get the issue number is to manually parse the `content_url` field:

```
[
  {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/projects/columns/cards/1478",
    "id": 1478,
    "node_id": "MDExOlByb2plY3RDYXJkMTQ3OA==",
    "note": "Add payload for delete Project column",
    "creator": {
      "login": "octocat",
      "id": 1,
      "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjE=",
      "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "created_at": "2016-09-05T14:21:06Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-09-05T14:20:22Z",
    "archived": false,
    "column_url": "https://api.github.com/projects/columns/367",
    "content_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/api-playground/projects-test/issues/3",
    "project_url": "https://api.github.com/projects/120"
  }
]
```

This seems pretty surprising to me, am i missing something? I'm just looking to figure out what the underlying `issue number` is so that I can do some manipulation of the labels.